# Recognizability/unique composition property for substitution tiling

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling, aperiodic-tiling

This may be a very basic question, but I have not found an answer to it so far in my search. The question is whether there is an "algorithmic" way to check unique-composition/recognizability of a tiling coming from a substitution. I am interested to know if one can reasonably check for any FLC substitution tiling whether it is aperiodic.

For example, if we take the symbolic case with $\mathcal{A}=\{ a,b,c,d \}$ and consider a substitution

$$ a\to ab, \quad b\to bc, \quad c\to da \quad \text{and} \quad d\to cd. $$

Is this substitution recognizable? And is there a method to build the unique composition?

Comment: The example is primitive, so recognizable. ("Of course" recognizability must be decidable in general, but I don't know a proof/reference.)

Comment: @VilleSalo But doesn't recognizability imply aperiodicity? I think I encountered an example of a primitive periodic substitution. Though I am probably missing something.

Comment: For example, I think a constant substitution $a,b,c,d\to abcd$ is a primitive substitution, but should definitely be periodic.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, you need also aperiodicity. Aperiodicity is decidable, look up the HD0L ultimate periodicity problem

Answer (score 0):

Following Ville Salo's comments I came across upon Pansiot's paper, [DECIDABILITY OF PERIODICITY FOR INFINITE WORDS](https://eudml.org/doc/92244). The papers shows an algorithm to decide whether an infinite word fixed by a substitution is aperiodic relying heavily on the Coven-Hedlund theorem regarding complexity of an infinite word.

If I am not mistaken, the crux of the paper is Lemma 2 discussing whether finite subwords have unique extension to a larger words. If  I am not mistaken, in the case I am interested the lemma simplifies to the following:

> Let $S:A\to A^+$ be an injective substition such that $\vert S^n(a)\vert\to \infty$ for all $a\in A$. Then $\omega=\lim_{n\to
> > \infty} S^n(a)$ is aperiodic if and only if $c_2(\omega)>c_1(\omega)$,
> where $c_k(\omega)$ is the number of $k$-subwords in $\omega$.

The original statement talks about having unique-extension\prolongablity of sub-words of the form $au\in A^+$, where $a\in A$ satisfies $\vert S^n(a)\vert\to \infty$  and $u\in A^*$. Since I assume every letter is growing, I can take the lemma with $u$ being the empty word.

I post this as an answer since I don't think I should add this in an edit to the original question. I would welcome and appreciate any corrections or pointing out if this argument is incorrect.

Comment: (Just for context, the decidability of HD0L periodicity which I mentioned is a vast generalization of this result.)

Comment: @VilleSalo I didn't want to diminish from the actual result, but for my purpose this was very easy to check and simple condition.